# How do I successfully port complex components with module federation and solid-js?

Tags: javascript, webhooks, webpack-module-federation, solid-js

I have been trying to learn Solid-js for a couple weeks now, and thought I'd try to work through a micro-frontend tutorial and settled on this Jack Herrington example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKKsjpH09dU

He's recently updated the final edition so it works on download and you can examine the working parts, but I've been using the Solid-js/Tailwind options for everything but the server. I'm stuck at the point of bringing the cart:Login/MiniCart to the home:Header (about 1:24:xx in the video).

I get an error about a null reference to "name", which actually refers to the component name in the dev bundle (generated by WP/MF). I assume the issue is with the way I've found that works to create the Login/MiniCart components, rather than how I'm bringing it in (but I'll post both, just in case).

I assume the issue is with persistence of webhooks, but as I'm new to both Module Federation and SolidJS, I'm unsure.

Here is a [link to the repo](https://github.com/CSworenI/solid-mfe/tree/master).

EDITs:
An offline suggestion has come in to show how Header is being invoked. In multiple places, it uses the same invocation with a different value for "name":

home/app.jsx: `<Header name='Home' />` || `import Header from './Header';`

pdp/app.jsx: `<Header name='Product Details' />` || `import Header from 'home/Header';`

cart/app.jsx: `<Header name='Cart' />` || `import Header from 'home/Header';`

I get the same error whether the prop is passed or not (removed fixtures from all pages to test).